# How to find the relationship between Hostlistener event target with ElementRef?

Tags: angular, angular8

I require to know that, getting click event target are child of my `element` from `viewChild` or outside of it. Is this possible to find?

I am not getting solution of it.

here is the code :

```
import { Component, ViewChild, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

 @ViewChild('child') element:ElementRef;

 @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target']) onClick(event) {
      const parent = this.element.nativeElement;

      if(event is childOf(parent)) {
        //
      } else {
        //
      }

     console.log(parent, event);
  }

  name = 'Angular';

}
```

How to achieve this?[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tvlz9q)

Any one help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Node.contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) method should be what you're looking for.

```
if(parent.contains(event)) {
  console.log('child')
} else {
  console.log('not a child')
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oeczs7?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

please try to use this approach

```
if (document.getElementById('idOfParentElement').contains(event.target)) {
// do something
}
```